# get selected item value throws IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter, android-listfragment

I create a list in a fragment with some mp3 files, then I pass this list to another fragment, which works, in this fragment I try to get the item value when the user presses one.

This following line of code does the job in the fragment where the list is created, but in this fragment it throws an IndexOutOfBoundsException.

```
String trackId = SD_PATH + songs.get(position);
```

Full code:

```
public class QueueListFragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String SD_PATH = new String(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/");
    private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.playlist_item2, songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);
    }

    public void onListReceived(List<String> songs) {

        ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.playlist_item2, songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);

    }

    @Override
    public void onListItemClick(ListView listView, View view, int position,
            long longId) {
        super.onListItemClick(listView, view, position, longId);


        String trackId = SD_PATH + songs.get(position);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), trackId, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }

}
```

Full Logcat:

```
02-27 21:47:54.300: W/dalvikvm(3781): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a70930)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.harteg.fragmentstest.QueueListFragment.onListItemClick(QueueListFragment.java:50)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment$2.onItemClick(ListFragment.java:58)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:298)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1100)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:2749)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3423)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
02-27 21:47:54.333: E/AndroidRuntime(3781):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Where are you initializing songs? Looks like songs is empty and you are trying to retrieve a value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're variable shadowing `songs`, so the class-scoped `songs` always has a size of `0`.
You declared `songs` and instantiated it at the top:

```
private List<String> songs = new ArrayList<String>(); size of 0
```

*However*, `onListReceived()` *also* has a variable named `songs`, and that is used when making the adapter.

You can do:

```
String trackId = SD_PATH + listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
```

or

```
String trackId = SD_PATH + listView.getAdapter().getItem(position);
```

or acually make the class `songs` point to the new list once `onListReceived()` is called:

```
 public void onListReceived(List<String> newSongs) {
        this.songs = newSongs;
        ArrayAdapter<String> songList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), R.layout.playlist_item2, songs);
        setListAdapter(songList);  
    }
```